# How to use experimental features in React?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I'm trying to play with an experimental feature in React. Specifically [react-call-return](https://github.com/facebook/react/tree/master/packages/react-call-return).

This is included as a package in React, but when installing latest from npm `react-call-return` is not included.

Is it possible to install this specific package from the repo with npm  without having to clone the entire repo? The package does exist on npm but at the moment it isn't being used: [react-call-return](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-call-return).

Any ideas on how to use this experimental feature?